Is there any way to call forgotPassword function of payloadcms manually?
Now I'm using payloadcms to create my web application.
You know, it supports built-in password recovery which can be used like this:
forgotPassword: {
    generateEmailHTML: async ({ req, token, user }: any) => {
        const url = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/auth/reset-password?token=${token}`
        console.log('URL', url)

        // return `Hey ${user.email}, reset your password by clicking here: ${url}`
        const email = SendVerifyEmailTemplate({ email: user.email, url })
        const ReactDOMServer = (await import('react-dom/server')).default
        return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(email);
    },
},

It works okay but what I'm worrying about is an attacker can use this api for email bombing.
So I want to add some verification to this endpoint.
But there's no verification option for this built-in service so I guess I should make an endpoint by myself.
Therefore I need to know how to use forgotPassword function of payloadcms module.
I can import the function like this:
import { forgotPasswordOperation } from 'payload/operations';

If you've already encountered to this problem and solved it, I need your help.

If you have any other idea to solve my problem, I'm always open to get it.

Try this
const token = await payload.forgotPassword({
    collection: 'users',
    data: {
        email: accountInfo.email,
    },
    disableEmail: true,
    req: req
})

There is a forgotPassword function in BasePayload type.
You can enable/disable email feature for you choice.
